# Edit user's information from local storage with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I am implementing the `editUser()` function. I create function to handle click button

```
$( "#table-list tbody" ).on( "click", ".btn-edit", function() {
operation = "E";

for (var i in tableStore) {
  var temp = JSON.parse(tableStore[i])
  if ($(this).attr("data-id") === temp.id) {
    $enterID.val(temp.id);
    $enterFirstName.val(temp.firstname);
    $enterLastName.val(temp.lastname);
    $enterLPhone.val(temp.phone);
    $enterEmail.val(temp.email);
    $enterAddress.val(temp.address);
    $enterBirthday.val(temp.birthday);
    $enterGender.val(temp.gender);
    $enterID.attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $enterFirstName.focus();
  }
}
```

});

this help me retrieve data from local storage. Then when I change some information on the `input` tag I wan to the data will updated into local storage. This is function help me do that:

```
function editUser(tableStore, user) {
  tableStore[tableStore] = user
  operation = "A"
}
```

and when the form is submit I handle it like that:

```
$( "#table-list tbody" ).on( "click", ".btn-delete", function() {
    selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id").replace("Delete", ""));
    $(this).parents('tr').remove()
    deleteUserInfor();
  });

  $(".form-information").on("click", ".btn-save-change", function () {
    if (operation == "A"){
      var newUser = readUserFromDOM();
      addUser(tableStore, newUser.serialize());
      localStorage.setItem("tableStore", JSON.stringify(tableStore));
    }
    else {
      var editingUser = readUserFromDOM();
      editUser(tableStore, editingUser.serialize());
      localStorage.setItem("tableStore", JSON.stringify(tableStore));
    }
  });
```

But some thing is wrong and I can't save the data. So can you help me show what is wrong is there.

This my code [user manager code pen](https://codepen.io/dienvm/pen/vmyjJa).

**Beside that**, the operation is not good idea for the pure function in js. If you can please help me to refactor it

Many thank for your help

Comment: `tableStore[tableStore] = user` well, that looks 3 types of wrong

Comment: Can you click my code pen link to understand more

Comment: no I won't - if the code here isn't the code you have an issue with, then you need to think about the question a bit more - I can't tell from what you've posted what that SHOULD be, I just know that what you are doing is completely wrong in that line alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Update:**

https://codepen.io/vikrant24/pen/ybgPww

As shown in below function:
 
You need to specify `tableStore[i]` value of `i`. Because `i` is the row number. If you are editing row 5th of grid then update `tableStore[4]=user` likewise if you are updating 3rd row then update `tableStore[2]=user`. I have added the code for it. I hope you understood.

```
function editUser(tableStore, user,i) {
  tableStore[i] = user
  operation = "A"
}
```

You should use this instead because eventually you would need to update that tableStore in localStorage:

```
function editUser(tableStore, user,i) {
      tableStore[i] = user;
      localStorage.setItem("tableStore", JSON.stringify(tableStore));
      operation = "A";
}
```

---

**Previous Answer**: 
**Use this function** It will work:

```
function editUser(tableStore, user) {
  tableStore[0] = user
  operation = "A"
}
```

You should use this instead because eventually you would need to update that `tableStore` in `localStorage`:

```
function editUser(tableStore, user) {
      tableStore[0] = user;
      localStorage.setItem("tableStore", JSON.stringify(tableStore));
      operation = "A";
}
```

Comment: It can save data into local, but it just save for the end items in array, how does it save the the current item I choose now

Comment: many thank you, It clear and helpful for me, the last question I post it `Beside that, the operation is not good idea for the pure function in js. If you can please help me to refactor it`. It mean that I create a global variable is opeation = 'A' and when I want to do edit function I switch it by opetation = 'E'. It not good ideal to do and not a pure function. Can you suggest me some idea to change it

Comment: I suggest you see this example http://jsfiddle.net/LCnt2/206/ . Try Indexed Database ,Web SQL.

Comment: I'm a begginer just learn javascript, I just use local storage to do it, database like Database ,Web SQ it to early. The purpose I try it how to apply OOP and modularity in this practice. `opetation = 'E'` it a global variable and it not good to apply for children function?

Do you understand?

Comment: Its OK to use global variable like `operation` as flag. Instead try using hidden fields for flag purpose.